# Counterintuinive AsynchronousSocketChannel behaviour

Tags: java, nio2

Look at the following test:

```
public class AsynchronousSocketTest {
  static PrintStream out=System.out;
  public static  void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    int port=9008;
    InetSocketAddress addr=new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port);
    AsynchronousChannelGroup acg=AsynchronousChannelGroup.withThreadPool(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
    // server not working, client trying to connect
    AsynchronousSocketChannel conn1=AsynchronousSocketChannel.open(acg);
    Future<Void> connfut1 = conn1.connect(addr); // no error, question 1
    Thread.sleep(100);
    out.println("connected1:"+connfut1.isDone());
    // start server
    AsynchronousServerSocketChannel assch=AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open(acg);
    assch.bind(addr);
    // accept
    Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> accfut1 = assch.accept();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    out.println("accepted1:"+accfut1.isDone());  // did not accept, question 2
    out.println("connected1:"+connfut1.isDone());  // did not connected
    // try new client connection
    AsynchronousSocketChannel conn2=AsynchronousSocketChannel.open(acg);
    Future<Void> connfut2 = conn2.connect(addr);
    Thread.sleep(100);
    out.println("connected2:"+connfut2.isDone()); // connected
    out.println("accepted1:"+accfut1.isDone());  // accepted
    // accept
    Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> accfut2 = assch.accept();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    out.println("accepted2:"+accfut2.isDone()); // not accepted
    out.println("connected1:"+connfut1.isDone()); // still waiting
  }
}
```

On Windows java 1.7.0_05 it prints:

```
 connected1:false
 accepted1:false
 connected1:false
 connected2:true
 accepted1:true
 accepted2:false
 connected1:false
```

The questions are:

1. why does the first `conn1.connect(addr)` not fail, although the server port is not bound yet?
2. why does the first `assch.accept()` not accept the already pending client connection?

I've read JDK's javadoc and could not find answers.

Comment: My guess is that the first ones times out silently, as the server does not respond when the initial contact is made, and no attemts to reconnect are done before `connfut2` which gets through as the server now is running.